# how do i get rid of laravel 10 route class error, where it says it can't find a class that is there?

Tags: class, routes, controller, laravel-blade, laravel-10

I just want to make an href link go to a different page from dashboard.
I have an error on my web page when i try to access my cities page through an href link
the error: "Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Cities\CitiesController] does not exist."
But it is located in App\Http\Controllers\Cities\

the dashboard.blade.php file

```
@extends('auth.layouts')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <a href="{{ route('cities') }}">Cities</a>
    </div>
</div>




@endsection
```

the CitiesController.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Cities;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;


class CitiesController extends Controller
{

    public function cities()
    {
        return view('auth.cities');
    }

}
```

and the web.php file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginRegisterController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Cities\CitiesController;

Route::get('/cities', [CitiesController::class, 'cities'])->name('cities');
```

I have tried chat-gpt 3.5 and 4 and both said to just check locations of them and in the end change nothing.
I have a login and register system as well, but i don't see why that would affect it, but everything else is the same
If needed this is the tutorial for the login/register: https://www.allphptricks.com/laravel-custom-user-registration-and-login-tutorial/

Comment: From your terminal, run `composer dump-autoload`, and look for any warnings (it'll say something like "doesn't comply with PSR-4", or similar). At a glance, this all looks ok... Is `CitiesController.php` in `app\Http\Controllers\Cities`? Or a different folder?

Comment: This is what shows up on composer dump-autoload, as the only yellow thing.
```
Class App\Http\Controllers\Cities\CitiesController located in ./app/Http/Controllers/Cities/ CitiesController.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
```
and the CItiesController.php is in App\Http\Controllers\Cities

Comment: I found the issues, I had a blank space before CitiesController.php

Comment: Excellent! Yeah, `composer dump-autoload` is your friend when you run into these "Cannot find Class" issues, when everything looks OK at a glance; it can help pinpoint the specific issue, although a blank space (or similar) is definitely harder to determine vs a casing/pluralization issue (`City` vs `city` vs `Cities` vs `cities`, etc.). Glad you got it sorted out though, cheers!